# Firebase: How to get the $id of an object after I authenticate using angularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

Firebase has the $onAuth method that listens for changes to the client's authentication state. If the client is authenticated, the callback will be passed an object that contains the uid. 
Here is my question:
Based on this uid, how can I get the the $id for this object.

This is how my data looks like in firebase:

```
profile {
   -K2a7k9GXodDriEZrM3f {
      email: "ale@aol.com"
      gravatar: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1d52da55055f0c8..."
      uid: "3f9e0d53-4e61-472c-8222-7fc9f663969e"
     name: "ale"
    }
}
```

I am using

```
auth.$onAuth(function (authData) {
    if (authData) {
      authData.profile = //here I want the $id of the object 
    }
})
```

All I see I can do with the authData response is to get the uid of the object by using:

```
$firebaseObject(ref.child('profile').child(authData.uid));
```

This authData does not contain the $id (i.e. the -K2a7k9GXodDriEZrM3f) of the object. And that is what I am looking for in order to have the user's information available. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: $id is a property of $firebaseArray records and does not exist on a $firebaseObject instance. In the case where you want the key of a $firebaseObject instance (not what the OP is looking for here), that's found in obj.$ref().key().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an object has a natural unique ID, you should usually store the object under that ID. Using push IDs in those cases adds no value and only complicates things.

Most developers using Firebase do as [the "Storing User Data" section in the documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing) illustrates: they store users by their uid. If you follow that guideline, you can find the key as `authData.uid`.

If you decide to stick to your current course, you can find the key for the user with:

```
ref.child('profile').orderByChild('uid').equalTo(authData.uid).once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

But you will be making it harder for the database to find your user, thus limiting the scalability of your app.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I have used the link you provided to store my user's data. Thank you so much!